# Break up long equation with square brackets into multiple lines

Tags: equations

I'm having trouble splitting the portion of the equation within[image] square brackets into two lines. How can it be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
\ \frac{d\langle  v_{dcL} \rangle  _0}{dt}&=\frac{1}{C_{dcL}}\Big[2{\langle  S_{D2} \rangle  ^R_1\langle  i_{tp} \rangle  ^R_1+\langle  S_{D2} \rangle  ^I_1\langle  i_{tp} \rangle  ^I_1-\langle  S_{i1} \rangle  ^R_1\langle  i_{fi1} \rangle  ^R_1 -\langle  S_{i1} \rangle  ^I_1\langle  i_{fi1} \rangle  ^I_1}\Big] \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it manually, with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\ \frac{d\langle  v_{dcL} \rangle  _0}{dt}&=\frac{1}{C_{dcL}}\Big[2 
\langle  S_{D2} \rangle  ^R_1\langle  i_{tp} \rangle  ^R_1+\\
&\langle  S_{D2} \rangle  ^I_1\langle  i_{tp} \rangle  ^I_1-\langle 
 S_{i1} \rangle  ^R_1\langle  i_{fi1} \rangle  ^R_1 -\langle  S_{i1}
  \rangle  ^I_1\langle  i_{fi1} \rangle  ^I_1 \Big] 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

and output is:

[image]